# Looping arcpy.mapping.updateLayers()?

Tags: arcpy, layers

I've got some problems with the following code, found on this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/80981/69986) to [Auto-updating symbology between *.mxds for same shapefile using arcgisscripting?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/is-there-a-way-to-auto-update-symbology-between-mxds-for-the-same-shapefile-p):

```
import arcpy.mapping as mmap

mxd = mmap.MapDocument("C:/Users/enclume/Carto/Cartes/UpdateTest/P_5_1.mxd")
DF = mmap.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Couches")[0]
sourcely = mmap.Layer("C:/Users/enclume/Carto/Cartes/Templates/Couches.lyr")
ly = mmap.ListLayers(mxd)[1]
mmap.UpdateLayer(DF, ly, sourcely, False)
The folder path containing my mxd's is: "C:/Users/enclume/Carto/Cartes/UpdateTest"
```

It looks fine when I run it, no error message, but nothing changes in the mxd. What am I doing wrong? As you see it, what is the expected outcome of this code segment?

If I ever find a solution, I would like to loop it. As I understands it, looping would repeat the updateLayer script to every mxd's in the specified file. But if it contains some subfolders, will the looping function find all mxd's in the folder and subfolder?

On the previously linked post, the person who wrote the comment said it would be possible to loop it using glob.glob. Can't find anything one this.

I also saw [Improving performance of looping over MXDs using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/65395/69986) which is about looping mxd's, but I can't seem to find a way to fuse those 2 scripts.

I'm new to using arcpy.

Can anyone help me with this 2-fold problem?

Comment: Do you have multiple dataframes in your .mxd and are you sure you have one called "Couches"? You might be better off not using the "Couches" search string. Also try calling mxd.save() at the end. I think this is what writes any changes to disk.

Comment: I have two dataframes "Couches" and "Couches sous la légende", that why I was using the search string. I'll add mxd.save() at the end and give it a try, thanks!

Comment: It worked! It's updating the mxd. Thanks @Dowlers! Now, how to loop this thing...!?

Answer (score 3):

List your mxd before you list your dataframe and layers

```
    import arcpy
    import os

    MxdFolderPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    if MxdFolderPath == '#' or not MxdFolderPath:
        MxdFolderPath = "C://Users//enclume//Carto//Cartes//UpdateTest"
    MxdCount = 0

    sourcelypath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    if sourcelypath == '#' or not sourcelypath:
        sourcelypath = "C://Users//enclume//Carto//Cartes//Templates//Couches.lyr"
    sourcely = arcpy.mapping.Layer(sourcelypath)


    arcpy.env.workspace = MxdFolderPath
    arcpy.AddMessage("   MXD PROCESSING")
    mxdList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")
    Mxdlen = len(mxdList)
    if Mxdlen == 0:
        arcpy.AddMessage( "   There are no mxd in: "+str(MxdFolderPath))
    else:
        arcpy.AddMessage( "   There are "+str(Mxdlen) +" mxd in: "+str(MxdFolderPath))

        for mxd in mxdList:
            MxdCount = (MxdCount +1)
            MxdPPath = os.path.join(MxdFolderPath,mxd)
            processingmxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MxdPPath)
            arcpy.AddMessage( " Mxd: "+ str(MxdCount)+" :"+str(mxd))
            dflist = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(processingmxd,"Couches")
            for df in dflist:
                    arcpy.AddMessage( " df: "+ str(df.name))
                    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(processingmxd, "Couches", df) #layers called Couches
                    for layer in layers:
                        arcpy.AddMessage("      Layer: "+str(layercount) +" :"+str(layer))
                        arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, layer, sourcely, False)
                        arcpy.AddMessage("      Layer Updated")
                        processingmxd.save()
            arcpy.AddMessage(" ")
    arcpy.AddMessage(" End")
```

I had most of this as a script tool already, I just added your wild cards. 
[image]

Comment: THANKS!!! We are near, I can feel it!! Awesome script by the way. When I run it, I get this message : 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 611, in __init__
    assert (os.path.isfile(mxd) or (mxd.lower() == "current")), gp.getIDMessage(89004, "Invalid MXD filename")
AssertionError: Invalid MXD filename.

Can you see what's wrong?

Comment: Do your mxd names conform to microsoft windows standards, and is mxd open?

Comment: BTW. Here's a folder crawl if you wanted to consider crawling folders: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179816/geoprocessing-in-violated-convention-environments-microsoft-windows

Comment: None of them are open. I think the names are conform: P.9.2.7.mxd, P.5.1_A.mxd, Tuilage.mxd, P_5_1.mxd and P.5.1.mxd. I tested most of them with the code in the post and they were fine. Is it because some of them are in a subfolder of "C://Users//enclume//Carto//Cartes//UpdateTest"?

Comment: I'm a newb, but what's a fodler crawl/crawling folder?

Comment: Windows naming conventions have far too many variables to put in a comment. The basics I conform to: use only alpha numeric characters except for the underscore. Never start with a numeric, don't use reserved words, and don't exceed 256 characters in the file name or full path... Your file name has full stops, so it breaks the convention. I'll test your file names on my computer..

Comment: A folder crawl allows you to loop through a target folder and all it's sub folders. In your case you might list all the folders and in each folder look for mxd... etc.

Comment: I used your file names and it worked in ArcCatalog. I ran it via ArcMap's ArcCatalog window and got the same error. Off the top of my head, I don't know why this would happen.

Comment: I updated the code to run it via ArcMap's ArcCatalog window.

Comment: Ran it from python window in a blank mxd (can't find how to run it from ArcCatalog). Now I get this error:  
Runtime error   
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)  
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1895, in UpdateLayer
    tc.ReplaceLayer(tl, rl)
ValueError: DataFrameObject: Unexpected error

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Adding_a_script_tool/00150000001r000000/ Did you put it in a script tool?

Comment: I've removed the layer counter (the line that was erroring for you).

Comment: Took away `+ str(layercount) `  in line 33, work perfectly! THANKS!!! Now I have to figure out how to do a folder crawl